# Mold on a single floating chilli seed in lacto-fermentation. Is this a problem?

Tags: fermentation, brining

I made my first attempt at lacto-fermentation and decided to ferment some chillis. I used a 3% salt water solution and currently 8 days into my first fermentation. I have encountered an issue and wanted to verify whether I should be concerned or these can be disregarded. The fermentation generally seems to be going well. However, there are very small white patches on one or two chillis (almost unnoticeable). Also there are two very insignificant instances of mold: One, on a single chilli seed that is floating on the surface, and another on a very small piece of freezer bag that is left outside the brine that I used to keep everything from floating. Are any of these issues? The two mold instances are each maybe 2 millimeters in diameter and are limited to the areas that have been left outside the brine.

Thanks in advance.